# Unable to change clearcase stream mastership?

Tags: stream, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm trying to change mastership of stream from "`BLR`" to "`LON`" but facing below error.

```
You must change mastership manually for the following branch types clearcase:
spider_dev_1.1@\spider_projects
```

Command using:

```
multitool chmaster –stream LON stream:spider_dev_1.1@\spider_projects.
```

How to get past this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try to do just that (ie. changing mastership manually for the branch type mentioned):

```
multitool chmaster LON brtype:spider_dev_1.1@\spider_projects
```

Then try again changing mastership of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have a bad feeling about this. Please tell me that this type name was a typo:
clearcase:spider_dev_1.1

Generally speaking, when you see a type name in the form foo:bar@\vobtag, it means that there was a type name conflict somewhere. And the name before the type name is a replica name.